# C# GlobalHook - The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#

I want to add `GlobalHook` to my program 
so i added event :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
}
```

And The Void

```
private void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    }
}
```

But when i start my code , error comes up with error :

> An unhandled exception of type *System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception*
>   occurred in Program.exe
>
> Additional information: The specified module could not be found

What i have to do to fix this ?
Why this error comes up ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Target .Net 2.0 on all the projects in your solution or at least those using the library and all will be fine.